# Patch PayPal API Shipping_Preference

Tags: paypal

I have a requirement to hide the shipping options on the paypal popup it's to a location I don't ship to. I have found this path that you can apparently set when you create the order, but I need to do it when they patch and some PayPal customers have multiple addresses.

```
/payment_source/paypal/experience_context/shipping_preference
```

I have tried to post:

```
{
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/payment_source/",
    "value": {
      "paypal": {
        "experience_context": {
          "shipping_preference": "NO_SHIPPING"
        }
      }
```

But I just get an error back saying:

> {"field":"value","location":"body","issue":"PATCH_VALUE_REQUIRED","description":"Please
> specify a 'value' to for the field that is being
> patched."},{"field":"path","value":"/payment_source/","location":"body","issue":"INVALID_JSON_POINTER_FORMAT","description":"Path
> should be a valid JSON Pointer https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6901
> that references a location within the request where the operation is
> performed."}],"message":"The requested action could not be performed,
> semantically incorrect, or failed business validation."

How can I do this and also return a Promise.reject() to make sure the user doesn't try to buy (this disables the complete button).

The alternative method I have thought, would be to hide the popup shipping options block using JS from the complete the final stage, is it possible to access the PayPal popup to show/hide elements on that popup? I just can't see a name to target that popup window if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't ship to an address, reject the promise.

That is all. No patching.

Comment: Ahh right, I was only patching on onshippingaddress change, not onshippingoptionchange too which was the cuase of my issue. I need to Promise.reject on both. Thx!